# Veracode insertion of sensitive information into sent data (CWE 201) using HttpClient.GetAsync()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpclient, veracode

I have a MVC application. I have a generic method that does HttpClient GetAsync
in which there is a low veracode flaw on this line

```
 HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress).Result;
```

Here is he Method.

```
 public static async Task<R?> SendSync<R>(string url)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            R? value = default;

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress).Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                value = await response.Content.ReadAsJsonAsync<R>();
            return value;
        }
```

How can I solve it?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this

Once I have set this line

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
```

the line

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress);
```

can we replaced with this

```
 HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Veracode is flagging this because of the possibility of exposing sensitive information over a network. You would have to ensure that you're not and if you're, discuss with your security team for a recommended approach, to securing your information.

In the case where you are not sending sensitive information, discuss with your security team, explaining that you're not and how you guys can go around mitigation(For more information dive [here](https://docs.veracode.com/r/Propose_Mitigating_Factors_for_a_Flaw)).

You can also go through a similar question in the Veracode community [here](https://community.veracode.com/s/question/0D53n00008B2clICAR/information-leakage-issue-cwe-201-209).